# How to display custom layout with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Edit: My original question was not good enough, so edited it now.

Hi Im new to angular and im trying to display a custom Layout
for my data list with ng-repeat. I cant use ng-class, as I would like to display diffent model vaules too.
I implemented a function in my controller, that calculates true or false according to my desired design. Then im trying to use ng-if to display my desired HTML with the data. The way I implemeted seems a bit awkward, especially if the layout gets more complicated, is there a better way to achieve this behaviour?
Here a sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/puE7OE?p=info

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.eventModels=[{name:'event1', description: 'description1'}, {name:'event2', description: 'description2'}, 
   {name:'event3', description: 'description3'}, {name:'event4', description: 'description4'}, 
   {name:'event5', description: 'description5'}, {name:'even6', description: 'description6'}, {name:'even7', description: 'description7'}];

    var counter = 0;
    this.isLarge = false;
    $scope.isLargeContainer = function() {
         if(counter === 0) {
            this.isLarge = true;
            counter++;
        } else {
            this.isLarge = false;
            if(counter === 2) {
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

View:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <section ng-repeat="(key, eventModel) in eventModels" >
    <div ng-init="isLargeContainer(eventModel)"></div> <!--the only way I found to call a function within the repeat directive.-->

        <div ng-if="isLarge">
            <!--Display large content -->
            <p class='large'>my large event: {{eventModel.name}}, {{eventModel.description}}</p>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="!isLarge">
            <!--Display content small-->
            <p class='small'>{{eventModel.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!
Im using Anguler 1.3.3

Comment: yes i agree, it should be closed. i tried to generalise and simplify the problem, but i clearly failed. should i just delete the whole question? i havent used stackoverflow that much, so im not sure whats better.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved your problem. You can find the solution here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/anasfirdousi/46saqLmw/
```

Here is the HTML

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function myController($scope){

$scope.msg = 'Learning Angular JS ng-class Directive';
    $scope.menu = [ 'Menu Item 1','Menu Item 2','Menu Item 3','Menu Item 4'];


    
    
}
```

```css
.large {
    font-size:16px;
    
}

body{
font-size:12px;    

}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    {{ msg }}

    <ul>    
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in menu"  ng-class="{'large': $index==2 }">  {{ value }} </li>
    </ul>
   

</div>
```

In your case, you actually have to use ng-class with expressions. The class is applied only if the condition holds true.

Comment: Another example for you if you want to check any specific condition, you call a function which returns a true or a false rather than using a inline expression.

http://jsfiddle.net/anasfirdousi/cuo6cn3L/

Comment: isn't that similar to what i mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @PSL Yes my dear you did the exact same thing and passed $index, I passed value, that's no difference. We composed our answers at the same time almost. While I was typing mine, I saw the toaster "1 new answer" :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/anasfirdousi/cuo6cn3L/

Check the above link. This is another example if you want to do it on any specific condition. You can call a function which checks a condition and returns either a true or a false rather than using an inline expression.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function myController($scope){

$scope.msg = 'Learning Angular JS ng-class Directive';
    $scope.menu = [ 'Menu Item 1','Menu Item 2','Menu Item 3','Menu Item 4'];
    $scope.CheckSometing =  function(v){
        
        
        if(v=='Menu Item 3'){
             return true;   
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
            
    }

    
    
}
```

```css
.large {
    font-size:16px;
    
}

body{
font-size:12px;    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    {{ msg }}

    <ul>    
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in menu"  ng-class="{'large': CheckSometing(value)  }">  {{ value }} </li>
    </ul>
   

</div>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. please check my edit. unfortuantely i made my example too simple and i dont think i can just use ng-class for my case.